# Javascript replace extension onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website, where I have gifs. Gifs are replaced by static images, after clicking on them, they are replaced with gif version. However, if user click on them 2nd time I would like to change to static version again. So far I got this:

The problem is, I cannot keep the originExt to png for example. If I click on it second time, the originExt will become .gif so it will change gif to gif. I would like to know how can I keep the .png after 1st click in that variable thanks

```
 $(function(){
     $('.gif').click(function(){
           var src = $(this).attr('src');
            var originExt = "."+src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

            if($(this).hasClass('play'))
            {
                $(this).attr("src", src.replace(/\.gif/i, originExt));
                $(this).removeClass('play');
            }   else
            {
                $(this).attr('src', 'sources/uploads/t/234.gif');
                $(this).addClass('play');
            }
          });
         });
```

Comment: you could add a data- attribute on each image which includes the original extension. Then just grab that inside your click function.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you could always store both the GIF-url and the PNG-url in data-attributes so you can just switch between them. So when your link doesn't have the `play` class, you set the `src` to the GIF-attribute.

Comment: Thank you guys, I stored the sources to gif and static img in data attributes. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Store the original extension in a a property and retrieve when needed:

```
$(function(){
     $('.gif').click(function(){
           var src = $(this).attr('src');

            if($(this).hasClass('play'))
            {
                // Here you retrieve the original extension from the element's property
                $(this).attr("src", src.replace(/\.gif/i, $(this).prop('origExt')));
                $(this).removeClass('play');
            }   else
            {
                // Here you get the original extension,and save it to a property of the element
                var originExt = "."+src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);   
                $(this).prop('origExt', originExt);
                $(this).attr('src', 'sources/uploads/t/234.gif');
                $(this).addClass('play');
            }
          });
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
$(function () {
    $('.gif').click(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        if (!$(this).attr('data-src')) $(this).attr('data-src', "." + src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));

        if ($(this).hasClass('play')) {
            $(this).attr("src", src.replace(/\.gif/i, $(this).attr('data-src')));
            $(this).removeClass('play');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('src', 'sources/uploads/t/234.gif');
            $(this).addClass('play');
        }
    });
});
```